# How to convert QKeyEvent::nativeModifiers() to UINT fsModifiers (for winapi RegisterHotKey)

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I have:

```
QKeyEvent* event; // I pressed "SHIFT"
modifiers = event->nativeModifiers(); // This is 513 value
RegisterHotKey(..., ..., modifiers, ...); // FAILED because 513 is bad modifier. 
//Right code of "SHIFT" is MOD_SHIFT = 0x0004
```

How to get the right native Windows modifier from `QKeyEvent` for winapi `RegisterHotKey` function?

Details:

> Qt 5.4; [QKeyEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html); [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it similarly to how [Qxt](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/src/master/src/widgets/win/qxtglobalshortcut_win.cpp) library converts the modifiers:

```
modifiers = event->nativeModifiers();

quint32 native = 0;
if (modifiers & Qt::ShiftModifier)
    native |= MOD_SHIFT;
if (modifiers & Qt::ControlModifier)
    native |= MOD_CONTROL;
if (modifiers & Qt::AltModifier)
    native |= MOD_ALT;
if (modifiers & Qt::MetaModifier)
    native |= MOD_WIN;

RegisterHotKey(..., ..., native, ...);
```

Comment: Does this mean the `nativeModifers()` function from qt is wrong?